# jqPlot Set color for each pie slice

Tags: jqplot

I see how to do this with a line graph, but I have to use a pie chart.

the task is I got a chart that outlines the status usage by a set product and I need to set one slice to be the same color always, but the issue is I can get the series code to work, and there's no good advice on it either.

what i want is, if we see something isn't being used a lot we want it the same color, otherwise it can just be whatever color.

```
example:
product #1 has sold 2 units in last 30 days
product #2 has sold 100 units in last 3 days
product #3 has sold 1 units in last 30 days
```

product #3 should be red, but the other two can be anything else.

currently I'm using seriesColors, but the data I want will not always be in a certain order so this is a poor solution for what I need.

I hope someone has some insight on this, and hopefully its possible.

I have to use jqPlot, so no suggestions on different libraries please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so put them as 1 over the sum of all the products sold. Then as for colors, create a set of colors you really think work together, and randomly select from your list (not including red). Then for the lowest item set the color to red.

If you can't use jqPlot, look into D3.js.

Comment: i have no choice on library its jqPlot. i dont understand what you're getting at, could you explain further?

Comment: You need to generate the seriesColors based on the data that's being passed in. That way your series will match the order of your items no matter how they get passed in.

Comment: that works perfectly. I made an array with colors and it works, don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks for your help +1

Answer (score 2):

```
seriesColors :[
               '#FF4700','#BA00FF',
               '#25FF00', '#5100FF',
               '#aa2211','#FFFF00',
               '#3377aa', '#FAE8FD',
               '#9933aa','#00FFED',
               '#9324A6', ''
              ],
```

Comment: Does that allow the data to be in a certain order?